# Math domain error when trying to graph equation of circle with polar coordinates in python

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am incredibly new to polar coordinates, and I just recently figured out the equation of a circle in polar coordinates (the equation is written in python):

```
r**2 + r0**2 - 2*r*r0*math.cos(theta - phi) = a**2
```

Where the polar coordinate `(r0, phi)` is the center of the circle, `a` is the radius of the circle and `(r, theta)` is any generic point on the circle. Thus, this can be simplified to solve for `r` as :

```
r = r0*math.cos(theta - phi) + math.sqrt(a**2 - r0**2 * math.sin(theta - phi)**2)
```

So to test this out, I have the following data setup.

```
r0 = math.sqrt(13) # (r0, phi) describes the center point ((3, 2) in Cartesian coords
phi = math.acos(3/r0)
a = 2 # radius is 2
```

So to solve for `r`, I pass in `math.pi/2` as the value for `theta`. This is where the math domain error occurs; for some reason `a**2 - r0**2 * math.sin(theta - phi)**2` evaluates to a negative number, which as far as I know should never happen (especially not for this circle). What am I doing wrong? Am I misinterpreting the equation or did I make a simple stupid error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK.
It simply means that your vertical line (theta = math.pi/2) does not intersect your circle.